# How to I change TKinter canvas line from dash to solid?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In my Python script, I initially created a canvas line as solid. Then under a certain event, I changed the line to dash using the syntax below.

```
self.canvas.itemconfig(line, dash=(4, 4))
```

What is the command to change it back to a solid line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass an empty tuple or list to `dash`.

```
self.canvas.itemconfig(line, dash=())
```